# Reducing Build and Deploy time on a Android MapView app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-maps, android-build

I am using Eclipse to build my application. If the application does not use Maps (MapView, MapActivity) then I can just hit Run, and it will build, deploy and launch the app on the phone. This takes about **5 seconds**.

Now, when I integrate MapView and MapActivity, I need to sign the apk every time. Which means, everytime providing that password 2 times, exporting it, going into command line and re-installing the app. This takes about **1 min**.

> Is there a way to automate this in Eclipse? Or is there a different way to build this quickly automatically.

Edit : 1 min may not seem huge, but over the course of the day, while developing I make about 5 builds in 15 mins. This is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to sign the apk every time. You can register your debug keystore to your Google Maps API console, the same way you did with your production keystore. That way the debug keystore has api access to Google Maps as well. See here for more info about the debug keystore: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks, saved me a lot of time here.